# Identify DU level when partially applied

Tags: reflection, f#, discriminated-union

Suppose we have a DU with 3x levels parameterised by reference types as shown:

```
type DU =
    | X of Object
    | Y of Object
    | Z of Object
```

Noting that the `GetUnionCases` function within the `FSharp.Reflection.FSharpType` namespace can, when provided with the type information for a DU, return a `UnionCaseInfo` array.

**I am looking for a function `f: ('T -> DU) -> UnionCaseInfo`, such that:**

- `f X` = `UnionCaseInfo` for level `X`.
- `f Y` = `UnionCaseInfo` for level `Y`.
- ...and so on.

Assuming a many-to-1 mapping between level and type parameter as shown at the start... **Is this even possible?**

*If* the `DU` levels were parameterless, the `GetProperties()` member provided by `typeof<DU>` contains singleton instances that can, via `PropertyInfo.Name`, be tied back to a corresponding `UnionCaseInfo`.

Alternatively... *If* the parameter type was different across **all** levels, we could do something akin to:

```
let x = X
```

Subsequently calling `x.GetType().GetMethods()` shows a `MethodInfo` for `Invoke(<some type>)`; using `<some type>` we could tie it back to the underlying level.

Unfortunately, neither of these methods (as far as I am aware) are suitable for this particular example!

Comment: I did not downvote, but I find the question a bit hard to understand. Perhaps it would be easier to follow if it was using a concrete example rather than X, Y, Z? One confusing things to me is what do you refer to when you talk about "levels"?

Comment: I thought "levels" was common usage but starting to realise that I might have just made it up without realising! In hindsight... The documentation suggests that "cases" would have been more appropriate. Thank you for the feedback regarding the wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you want a function `getUnionCase` that will return `UnionCaseInfo` when you call it with just the constructor (which is treated as a function) as argument.

You could try doing this by using reflection to call the function with `null` as an argument and then inspecting the result. This seems to work (but I'm sure there are corner cases when it fails, e.g. when you use `CompilationRepresentationFlags.UseNullAsTrueValue` on your DU):

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let getUnionCase ctor = 
  let value = 
    if FSharpType.IsFunction(ctor.GetType()) then 
      ctor.GetType().GetMethod("Invoke").Invoke(ctor, [| null |])
    else ctor
  let tag = value.GetType().GetProperty("Tag").GetValue(value) :?> int
  FSharpType.GetUnionCases(value.GetType())
  |> Seq.find (fun uc -> uc.Tag = tag)

getUnionCase X
getUnionCase Y
getUnionCase Z
```

A more clever trick would be to use automatic quoting of parameters, which has to be done in a static member, but it should be much more robust method:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

type Helper = 
  static member GetCase([<ReflectedDefinition>]e:Expr<'T>) = 
    match e with 
    | Patterns.NewUnionCase(uc, _)
    | Patterns.Lambda(_, Patterns.NewUnionCase(uc, _)) -> uc

Helper.GetCase(X)
Helper.GetCase(Y)
Helper.GetCase(Z)
```

For reference, I tested this with a slightly more interesting DU:

```
type DU =
  | X of Object
  | Y of int
  | Z
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas... For my purposes your initial suggestion to call the function with `null` more than suffices for my needs. However... Your latter approach is really interesting to see and far more elegant/robust; I've definitely learned something new there.